# AngularJS - Calling Flickr API fails with warning message

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flickr, browser-security

I have a simple AngularJS app that allows one to search for Flickr photos. The problem is in IE I get the the following message when I call the Flickr API:

*This page is accessing information that is not under its control. This poses a security risk. Do you want to continue?*

If I click Yes, the app works and loads the relevant photos. However, in Chrome and Firefox I do not get any message and nothing happens - no photos are loaded.

Here is the code:

```
function PhotoController($scope, photoData) {
    $scope.thumbSize = 'small';
    $scope.setThumbSize = function (size) { $scope.thumbSize = size; };

    $scope.submitSearch = function getPhotos() {
        $scope.photos = [];
        $scope.items = [];

        photoData.getAllItems($scope.searchKeyword).then(function (data) {
            var parsedData = angular.fromJson(data);
            $scope.items = parsedData.photos.photo;

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
                var photo = $scope.items[i];
                $scope.photos.push({ title: photo.title, thumbUrl: ' http://farm' + photo.farm + '.staticflickr.com/' + photo.server + '/' + photo.id + '_' + photo.secret + '_m.jpg' });
            }
        },
        function (errorMessage) {
            $scope.error = errorMessage;
        });

    };
}

angular.module('photoApp').factory('photoData', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        getAllItems: function (keyWord) {
            //Creating a deferred object
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var apiUrl = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=myAPIkey&tags=' + keyWord + '&format=json&nojsoncallback=1';

            //Calling Web API to fetch pics
            $http.get(apiUrl).success(function (data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function () {
                deferred.reject("An error occured while fetching photos");
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
});
```

How do I get rid of the message and make it work in Chrome/Firefox?

**UPDATE: I changed the code to the below based on joakimbl's plunker and it now runs in Chrome and FF but IE still throws the warning message.**

```
var app = angular.module("photoApp", []);

app.controller('PhotoController', function ($scope, photoData) {
    $scope.thumbSize = 'small';
    $scope.setThumbSize = function (size) { $scope.thumbSize = size; };

    $scope.submitSearch = function getPhotos() {
        $scope.photos = [];
        $scope.items = [];

        photoData.getAllItems($scope.searchKeyword).then(function (data) {
            var parsedData = angular.fromJson(data);
            $scope.items = parsedData.photos.photo;

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
                var photo = $scope.items[i];
                $scope.photos.push({ title: photo.title, thumbUrl: ' http://farm' + photo.farm + '.staticflickr.com/' + photo.server + '/' + photo.id + '_' + photo.secret + '_m.jpg' });
            }
        },
        function (errorMessage) {
            $scope.error = errorMessage;
        });
    };
});

app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
});

app.factory('photoData', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        getAllItems: function (keyWord) {
            //Creating a deferred object
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var apiUrl = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=84ad829261f6347dbfc4bf23fc1afdbd&tags=' + keyWord + '&format=json&nojsoncallback=1';

            //$http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
            //delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

            //Calling Web API to fetch pics
            $http.get(apiUrl).success(function (data) {
                //Passing data to deferred's resolve function on successful completion
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function (error) {
                //Sending a friendly error message in case of failure
                deferred.reject("An error occured while fetching items");
            });
            //Returning the promise object
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
})
```

;

Comment: jsonp request could also work in your case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `X-Requested-With` request header causes problems - [see this question for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661032/http-get-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-but-ajax-is/16662590#16662590). The following code should fix the problem:

```
angular.module('photoApp').config(function($httpProvider){
  delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
});
```

Comment: I added your code after the angular.module('photoApp').factory... section but I still get the same message. Do I need to add it in somewhere else?

Comment: No, that should do the trick, the config runs before the facory methods - I've created this plunker which works in chrome: http://plnkr.co/edit/TQrCBl51iz7Ecg2POxNM?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the plunker! I updated my code based on your plunker - see my edited question. It runs fine in Chrome and FF but IE still throws the warning message. Any ideas how to get rid of the message?

Comment: I don't think there's any easy solution to this. It works fine in IE10, but CORS have some issues on older versions of IE: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1047 - I'd recommend using jsonp if possible

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with IE10. I added the url which makes CORS call as a trusted site in IE10 and it worked fine. I suggest you do the same. Perhaps it will help.