# Getting `Unexpected token :` in angularjs but cannot use callback

Tags: json, angularjs, jsonp, spotify

I'm trying to query the [Spotify Metadata API](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/lookup/) with AngularJS but I keep running into the following error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Now I know typically when querying you should add `callback=JSON_CALLBACK` as a query string but in this case it won't work. It returns:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
```

I am using `$http.jsonp()`.

[Example without callback](http://jsfiddle.net/WolfieZero/x5RcT/1/) | [Example with callback](http://jsfiddle.net/WolfieZero/MFa9d/1/)

So, is there a way around this using pure Javascript or I'm best add a server-side wrapper (which I've got working but rather if it was pure Javascript)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't seem like Spotify is providing jsonp support, but they do support CORS - so this should work:

```js
function spotify_api($http) {
    var url = "http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/.json?uri=spotify:track:5PJSqY8jbYzr4a6dl5Ory1";
    //CORS support
    delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

    $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

See my update: http://jsfiddle.net/69kYH/

The bad news is that CORS doesn't seem to work properly in angular with older versions of IE - see [AngularJS - Calling Flickr API fails with warning message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690555/angularjs-calling-flickr-api-fails-with-warning-message/16691258#16691258)