# Issues with CORS. Flask <-> AngularJS

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, angularjs, flask

Starting a new project with a angularjs client app and a flask app providing the api. I'm using mongodb as the database. I had to immediately rule out jsonp since I would need the ability to POST across different ports. So we have localhost:9000 for the angular app and localhost:9001 for the flask app.

I went through and made the changed needed for CORS in my API as well as my angular files. See source below. First issue I ran in to was that there is a bug that CORS allow header does not recognize localhost in Chrome. I updated my hosts file so I could use moneybooks.dev and this worked for my GET requests without using JSONP.

Now, to the issues I'm facing. When submitting a POST request, its stating `Origin http://moneybooks.dev:9000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin` What? GET can go through but POST is declined. I see the request come through to flask but it returns HTTP 400. I need help making POST requests work.

Another issue, which may be related, is that on my GET requests, sometimes the GET request doesn't fire at all. Like in `BudgetCtrl` the loadBudget function. On #/budgets/budgetID the name of the budget will sometimes not load at all. I check the flask log and don't see a request coming through. Then I click refresh, I see the request, the budget name appears on the page however in the flask log I see an error. `[Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.` Its a connection error that only appears in the flask log when the GET request succeeds.

Are these issues related? Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('MoneybooksApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngResource'])
  .config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]);
```

**budgets.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('MoneybooksApp')
  .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/budgets', {
        templateUrl: 'views/budgets-list.html',
        controller: 'BudgetListCtrl'
      })
      .when('/budgets/:budgetID', {
        templateUrl: 'views/budget.html',
        controller: 'BudgetCtrl'
      });
  }])
  .controller('BudgetListCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $resource) {
    $scope.budgets = [];

    var init = function () {
      $scope.loadBudgets();
    }

    $scope.loadBudgets = function() {
      $http.get('http://moneybooks.dev:9001/api/budgets')
        .success(function (data) {
          $scope.budgets = data;
        })
        .error(function (data) {
          console.error(data);
        });
    };

    init();
  })
  .controller('BudgetCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $resource) {
    $scope.budget = {};

    var init = function () {
      $scope.loadBudget();
    };

    $scope.loadBudget = function() {
      $http.get('http://moneybooks.dev:9001/api/budgets/'+$routeParams['budgetID'])
        .success(function (data) {
          $scope.budget = data;
        })
        .error(function (data) {
          console.error(data);
        });
    };

    init();
  })
  .controller('TransactionCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $resource) {
    $scope.transactions = [];
    $scope.editing = false;
    $scope.editingID;

    var init = function () {};


    $scope.syncUp = function () {
      $http.post('http://moneybooks.dev:9001/api/budgets/'+$routeParams['budgetID']+'/transactions', {transactions: $scope.transactions});
    };

    $scope.syncDown = function () {
      $http.get('http://moneybooks.dev:9001/api/budgets/'+$$routeParams['budgetID']+'/transactions')
        .success(function (transactions) {
          $scope.transactions = transactions;
        });
    };

    $scope.add = function() {
      $scope.transactions.push({
        amount: $scope.amount,
        description: $scope.description,
        datetime: $scope.datetime
      });

      reset();
      $scope.defaultSort();
    };

    $scope.edit = function(index) {
      var transaction = $scope.transactions[index];

      $scope.amount = transaction.amount;
      $scope.description = transaction.description;
      $scope.datetime = transaction.datetime;

      $scope.inserting = false;
      $scope.editing = true;
      $scope.editingID = index;
    };

    $scope.save = function() {
      $scope.transactions[$scope.editingID].amount = $scope.amount;
      $scope.transactions[$scope.editingID].description = $scope.description;
      $scope.transactions[$scope.editingID].datetime = $scope.datetime;

      reset();
      $scope.defaultSort();
    };

    var reset = function() {
      $scope.editing = false;
      $scope.editingID = undefined;

      $scope.amount = '';
      $scope.description = '';
      $scope.datetime = '';
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
      reset();
    };


    $scope.remove = function(index) {
      $scope.transactions.splice(index, 1);
      if ($scope.editing) {
        reset();
      }
    };

    $scope.defaultSort = function() {
      var sortFunction = function(a, b) {
        var a_date = new Date(a['datetime']);
        var b_date = new Date(b['datetime']);

        if (a['datetime'] === b['datetime']) {
          var x = a['amount'], y = b['amount'];
          return x > y ? -1 : x < y ? 1 : 0;
        } else {
          return a_date - b_date
        }
      };

      $scope.transactions.sort(sortFunction);
    };

    $scope.descriptionSuggestions = function() {
      var suggestions = [];

      return $.map($scope.transactions, function(transaction) {
        if ($.inArray(transaction.description, suggestions) === -1){
          suggestions.push(transaction.description);
          return transaction.description;
        }
      });
    };

    $scope.dateSuggestions = function () {
      var suggestions = [];

      return $.map($scope.transactions, function(transaction) {
        if ($.inArray(transaction.datetime, suggestions) === -1){
          suggestions.push(transaction.datetime);
          return transaction.datetime;
        }
      });
    }

    $scope.getRunningTotal = function(index) {
      var runningTotal = 0;
      var selectedTransactions = $scope.transactions.slice(0, index+1);
      angular.forEach(selectedTransactions, function(transaction, index){
        runningTotal += transaction.amount;
      });
      return runningTotal;
    };

    init();

    $(function(){
      (function($){
        var header = $('#budget-header');
        var budget = $('#budget');
        var pos = header.offset();

        $(window).scroll(function(){
          if ($(this).scrollTop() > pos.top && header.css('position') == 'static') {
            header.css({
              position: 'fixed',
              width: header.width(),
              top: 0
            }).addClass('pinned');
            budget.css({
              'margin-top': '+='+header.height()
            });
          } else if ($(this).scrollTop() < pos.top && header.css('position') == 'fixed') {
            header.css({
              position: 'static'
            }).removeClass('pinned');
            budget.css({
              'margin-top': '-='+header.height()
            });
          }
        });
      })(jQuery);
    });
  });
```

**API.py**

```
from flask import Flask, Response, Blueprint, request
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.json_util import dumps
from decorators import crossdomain
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json

class APIEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, objectid.ObjectID):
            return str(obj)

app = Flask(__name__)

client = MongoClient()
db = client['moneybooks']

api = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix="/api")

@api.route('/budgets', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'])
@crossdomain(origin='*', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'], headers=['X-Requested-With', 'Content-Type', 'Origin'])
def budgets():
    if request.method == "POST":
        budget_id = db.budgets.insert({
            'name': request.form['name']
        })
        budget_json = dumps(db.budgets.find_one({'_id': budget_id}), cls=APIEncoder)

    if request.method == "GET":
        budget_json = dumps(db.budgets.find(), cls=APIEncoder)

    return Response(budget_json, mimetype='application/json')

@api.route('/budgets/<budget_id>', methods=['GET', 'OPTIONS'])
@crossdomain(origin='*', methods=['GET', 'OPTIONS'], headers=['X-Requested-With', 'Content-Type', 'Origin'])
def budget(budget_id):
  budget_json = dumps(db.budgets.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(budget_id)}), cls=APIEncoder)
  return Response(budget_json, mimetype='application/json')

@api.route('/budgets/<budget_id>/transactions', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'])
@crossdomain(origin='*', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'], headers=['X-Requested-With', 'Content-Type', 'Origin'])
def transactions(budget_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        db.budgets.update({
            '_id': ObjectId(budget_id)
        }, {
            '$set': {
                'transactions': request.form['transactions']
            }
        });
        budget_json = dumps(db.budgets.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(budget_id)}), cls=APIEncoder)

    if request.method == "GET":
        budget_json = dumps(db.budgets.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(budget_id)}).transactions, cls=APIEncoder)

    return Response(budget_json, mimetype='application/json')

app.register_blueprint(api)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.config['debug'] = True
    app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True
    app.run()
```

**decorators.py**

```
from datetime import timedelta
from flask import make_response, request, current_app
from functools import update_wrapper

def crossdomain(origin=None, methods=None, headers=None, max_age=21600, attach_to_all=True, automatic_options=True):
    if methods is not None:
        methods = ', '.join(sorted(x.upper() for x in methods))
    if headers is not None and not isinstance(headers, basestring):
        headers = ', '.join(x.upper() for x in headers)
    if isinstance(max_age, timedelta):
        max_age = max_age.total_seconds()

    def get_methods():
        if methods is not None:
            return methods

        options_resp = current_app.make_default_options_response()
        return options_resp.headers['allow']

    def decorator(f):
        def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
            if automatic_options and request.method == 'OPTIONS':
                resp = current_app.make_default_options_response()
            else:
                resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
            if not attach_to_all and request.method != 'OPTIONS':
                return resp

            h = resp.headers
            h['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = origin
            h['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = get_methods()
            h['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = str(max_age)

            if headers is not None:
                h['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = headers
            return resp

        f.provide_automatic_options = False
        f.required_methods = ['OPTIONS']
        return update_wrapper(wrapped_function, f)
    return decorator
```

**Edit**

Output from chrome dev console.

Console:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://moneybooks.dev:9001/api/budgets/5223e780f58e4d20509b4b8b/transactions. Origin http://moneybooks.dev:9000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Network

```
Name: transactions /api/budgets/5223e780f58e4d20509b4b8b
Method: POST
Status: (canceled)
Type: Pending
Initiator: angular.js:9499
Size: 13 B / 0 B
Latency: 21 ms
```

Comment: Can you post the request/response headers for a post request. They will be more relevant than source code. Also have you tried posting to your server using curl? That is often helpful in diagnosing problems.

Comment: I sent a POST request using a chrome extension `Dev HTTP Client`, which allows you generate HTTP requests. Those POST requests work fine and insert in to the DB. Not sure where to get the headers you're looking for. Here is what I see in the Flask log output: `127.0.0.1 -- [02/Sep/2013 21:30] "OPTIONS /api/budgets/<budgetID>/transactions HTTP1.1" 200` - `127.0.0.1 -- [02/Sep/2013 21:30] "POST/api/budgets/<budgetID>/transactions HTTP1.1" 400`

Comment: Chrome Dev tools, network panel -https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: I edited my question with that information. I find it odd that its canceled/pending?

Comment: I had similar problems but it was fixed by removing the 'requested with' header http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661032/http-get-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-but-ajax-is

Comment: Unfortunately I'm already deleting that header if you look in app.js. I'm at a stopping point until I can figure this out because I refuse to shove this angular app in to the flask app. Clunky, slow and feels weird.

Comment: @Kylee Can you click on the `POST` request in the network panel of the Chrome dev tools, and show us the contents of the 'request headers' and 'response headers' sections?

Comment: Its worth noting that Chrome Dev Tools has a 'bug' where it will show that CORS failed when the server returns an error.  It will never show the error and you may think it had something to do with CORS.  Double check, use Firebug.  Firebug will show the server's response that fails CORS.

Comment: I assume that since my answer was accepted and awarded the bounty, your problem has been solved?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I thought my comment had posted. Issue resolve. Whoo!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @TheSharpieOne pointed out, the CORS error is likely a red herring caused by a Chrome Dev Tools bug.  If it was an actual CORS issue, the pre-flight OPTIONS call should have returned the same error.

I believe your 400 error may be coming from `request.form['transactions']` in the handler for the POST request.  `request.form` is a MultiDict datastructure and according to the documentation at http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict:

> From Werkzeug 0.3 onwards, the KeyError raised by this class is also a subclass of the BadRequest HTTP exception and will render a page for a 400 BAD REQUEST if caught in a catch-all for HTTP exceptions.

I believe that if you check for the 'transactions' key in `request.forms.keys()`, you'll find that it does not exist.  Note that the content type for the POST is `application/json` not `x-www-form-urlencoded`.  According to the documentation at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.get_json, you'll want to get the request data using the `request.get_json()` function when the request mimetype is `application/json`.

Answer (score 0):

Is the POST sending content ?  I had a similar issuee when the body was null.  If it is, adding either an empty body ("") when the object is falsy, or adding the ContentLength header as 0 both seemed to work.

```
$scope.syncUp = function () {
var objToSend = $scope.transactions ? { transactions: $scope.transactions } : "";
$http.post('http://moneybooks.dev:9001/api/budgets/'+$routeParams['budgetID']+'/transactions', objToSend);
};
```

Comment: That's what I thought but $scope.transactions is set to [] at the top of the controller so it should still send something even if its an empty array. I did try your code and still getting the same error that http://moneybooks.dev:9000 is not allowed by origin.

Answer (score -2):

Ensure app.js is included before budget.js in your HTML page

Comment: It is before budget.js. Everything works except for POST requests.