# AngularJS 1.2 cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Is there any way to configure Angular app to make it available?
Im using a factory.

By the way, I'm using localhost as webserver but I'm making a request to other server (same network).

```
angular.module('demoApp.factories', [])
    .factory('dataFactory', ['$http', function($http) {

    var urlBase = 'external-server:8080';
    var dataFactory = {};
    dataFactory.getTest = function () {
        return $http.get(urlBase + '/test');
    };

    return dataFactory;
}]);
```

Comment: Maybe if I use jQuery for this part instead?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661032/http-get-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-but-ajax-is

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS Error: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742070/angularjs-error-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes)

Answer (score 4):

Finally found the solution. Will post here, maybe it can help others:

```
angular.module('demoApp.factories', [])
    .factory('dataFactory', ['$http', function($http) {

    var urlBase = 'external-server:8080';
    var dataFactory = {};
    dataFactory.getTest = function () {
        //Note the $http method changed and a new parameter is added (callback)
        //the value of the callback parameter can be anything
        return $http.jsonp(urlBase + '/test?callback=myCallback');
    };

    return dataFactory;
}]);
```

The controller file basically just calling this factory:

```
angular.module('demoApp.controllers', []).controller('controller1', ['$scope', 'dataFactory', 
        function ($scope, dataFactory) {

    $scope.status;
    $scope.data;
    dataFactory.getTest().success(function (data) 
    {
        $scope.data = data;
    }).error(function (error) 
    {
        $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
    });
```

Comment: This will only enable you to do GET requests cross-domain. If you want do to POST,PUT or DELETE for example u'll need to enable CORS in your client and API.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking to configure the $httpProvider as specified here: http://better-inter.net/enabling-cors-in-angular-js/

Another way is to create a simple http proxy on your front-end server to make external requests look like to angular that they're coming from the same server.