# Connect PhoneGap App to MySql Database on the server with Angularjs and php?

Tags: php, mysql, json, angularjs, cordova

Hi I'm trying to get data from a MySQL Database on my Server with a Phonegap App. I'm calling a php file on the server wich is giving me back JSON. I'm trying to do a ajax call on that php file on the server and I want to save the json data in the $scope of angular so I can use it in my HTML. My script looks like this:

```
     function PostsCtrlAjax($scope, $http)

     {

        var output2 = $('#output2');
        $.ajax({
               url: 'http://myWebsiteMySQL.ch/landmarks.php',
               dataType: 'jsonp',
               jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
               timeout: 5000,
               success: function(data, status){

                      $scope.posts = data;
               },
               error: function(){
               output2.text('There was an error loading the data.');
               }
               });

     }

  </script>
```

then I want to access the $scope data in the html file like so:

```
<div id="ng-app" ng-app ng-controller="PostsCtrlAjax">
        <div ng-repeat="post in posts" class='postBody'>
            <div>{{post.id}}</div>
            <div>{{post.name}}</div>
         </div>  
</div>
```

but I can't see any data. What am I doing wrong?
I'm thankful for any help. I'm trying to solve this problem since 2 days.

my php file on the server looks like this:

```
 <?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$server = "localhost";
$username = "xx";
$password = "xx";
$database = "xx";

$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $con);

$sql = "SELECT id, l_name AS name, l_lat AS latitude, l_long AS longitude, l_image AS bild FROM landmarks ORDER BY l_name";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());

$records = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $records[] = $row;
}

mysql_close($con);

echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';
?>
```

the Data which is send back is this:

```
([{"id":"14","name":"Fashion_Coupons","latitude":"9.000000000000","longitude":"9.000000000000","bild":null},{"id":"13","name":"Travel_Coupons","latitude":"3.000000000000","longitude":"4.000000000000","bild":"TopTrendsProgressbar.png"},{"id":"31","name":"Travel_Coupons","latitude":"222.000000000000","longitude":"23212.000000000000","bild":null}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add watch method for detecting change 'posts' in Your model, something like this:

```
$scope.$watch('_rows', function() {
    $scope.items = $scope.posts;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See this answer for how to do a JSONP request in angular. [AngularJS 1.2 cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990141/angularjs-1-2-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http)

Note that the documentation says JSONP URLs must contain the string JSON_CALLBACK. http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.$http#jsonp

```
$http.jsonp('http://myWebsiteMySQL.ch/landmarks.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
    .success(function (data) 
    {
        $scope.posts = data;
    });
```

You can add an error callback to see if that contains any useful info. Chain a .error after the .success callback.

```
$http.jsonp('http://myWebsiteMySQL.ch/landmarks.php')
    .success(function (data) { ...  })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
```

Comment: I tried this but it seems as it is not doing a success. When I alert a message before $scope.posts = data; it won't alert. So I think it's failing. Do I need to do something with CORS?

Comment: Is your php actually returnning a JSONP payload? Add

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm new on this field, I just updated my code above with my php file which is on the server. I tried it now wit $http.get and it's entering the success funtion but $scope.posts = data is still not able to be called with {{post.id}}

Comment: Post the data that's being sent, I'm not familiar with PHP and don't want to try and learn it to debug this issue for you.

Comment: it looks like you need `callback=JSON_CALLBACK` in your query string.