# Why Angular $http.get() from Yahoo returns 404?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

This is my code:

```
var url = "http://www.google.com/finance?q=MSFT" 
$http.get(url).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert('successful');
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert('failed');
});
```

This is working fine. However, if I change the url to Yahoo or Reuters as follows, it always returns 404 error.

```
url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=MSFT";
url = "http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/companyProfile?rpc=66&symbol=MSFT"
```

Those are all valid URLs when you enter into Chrome.

I understand there are related questions about `$http.get` at stackoverflow, but I tried some suggestions and still can't make it work. I'm very curious why the same request works for Google, but not for Yahoo and Reuters?

**UPDATE 1:**
As some suggested it may be a CROSS-ORIGIN problem, so I added the following code from [here](http://better-inter.net/enabling-cors-in-angular-js/) to my project:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}]);
```

However, it doesn't help.

I looked at Network traffic log in Chrome, the request status is (canceled). Any clue why?

**UPDATE 2:**
Actually, I overlooked the error message in Chrome console. it shows:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=MSFT. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:1486' is therefore not allowed access.
```

So, it does seem to be a Cross-Origin issue. However, the UPDATE 1 code doesn't seem to have any effect on this. What did I do wrong? Also, why it didn't complain about Google?

Comment: Do you have perhaps an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error?

Comment: data in error callback is empty string.

Comment: As I told you, this is exactly an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. This is because both websites doesn't allow Cross-Origin requests. 
You can bypass this running Chrome with `--disable-web-security` flag. Firefox should work as is though.

Comment: Okay, I got it now. Thanks. However, I still don't understand why this isn't a problem for accessing Google site?

Comment: Because they *probably* set something like ` header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`  which allows any origin.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a cross-origin request issue.

Someone with a similar problem found a way to do cross-origin requests with angular here: [AngularJS 1.2 cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990141/angularjs-1-2-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http)

and probably a more relevant topic here: [$http.get is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin but $.ajax is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661032/http-get-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-but-ajax-is)

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I tried to delete 'X-Requested-With', but it didn't help.