# AngularJS Error: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I have three files of a very simple angular js application

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gemStore">
  <head>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
      <div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in store.products">
        <h3>{{product.name}} <em class="pull-right">{{product.price | currency}}</em></h3>
      </div>

  <product-color></product-color>
  </body>
</html>
```

**product-color.html**

```
<div class="list-group-item">
    <h3>Hello <em class="pull-right">Brother</em></h3>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);

  app.controller('StoreController', function($http){
              this.products = gem;
          }
  );

  app.directive('productColor', function() {
      return {
          restrict: 'E', //Element Directive
          templateUrl: 'product-color.html'
      };
   }
  );

  var gem = [
              {
                  name: "Shirt",
                  price: 23.11,
                  color: "Blue"
              },
              {
                  name: "Jeans",
                  price: 5.09,
                  color: "Red"
              }
  ];

})();
```

I started getting this error as soon as I entered an include of product-color.html using custom directive named productColor:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/product-color.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
angular.js:11594 Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/product-color.html'.
```

What may be going wrong? Is it a path issue for product-color.html?

All my three files are in the same root folder `C:/user/project/`

Comment: Just a quick pointer that if you do something stupid, such as in my case I accidentally appended the TLD to the port: "http://localhost:8070.com" then you will receive the same error. Check what URL you're attempting to resolve!

Comment: Maybe similar in here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local/38320697#38320697

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP." error when loading a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local)

Answer (score 308, accepted):

This error is happening because you are just opening html documents directly from the browser. To fix this you will need to serve your code from a webserver and access it on localhost. If you have Apache setup, use it to serve your files. Some IDE's have built in web servers, like JetBrains IDE's, Eclipse...

If you have Node.Js setup then you can use [http-server](https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server). Just run `npm install http-server -g` and you will be able to use it in terminal like `http-server C:\location\to\app`.

Comment: The http-server is the simplest way I've seen of hosting locally. 
Note: If you don't have npm on windows, just install node.js and it'll become available in cmd.

Comment: And if it's happened in webview in android, what should i do!?

Comment: Perfect... it was opened in the browser but as soon as I opened it with mamp it worked. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. Anyway, I go in the folder where there are my html and js files to be runned, so I run "http-server index.html". At this point, cmd says:
Starting up http-server, serving index.html
Available on:
http://192.168.1.8:8080
etc...

If I put in the url: "http://192.168.1.8:8080" in the browser downloades something...if I open it with the browser, I can't see the correct page...

Comment: I use my Angular APP with electron. How can i launch server

Comment: Out of curiosity, why isn't it possible to just open the files in the web browser ?

Comment: @UtenteStack I have the same problem, please help as I tried the above solution but it did not work

Comment: To extend this solution:  If you have node setup up and would like to serve with live-reload you can use [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server)

Comment: @reddy Plain and simple: It is a security issue for the browser to access the  filesystem directly on your computer.

Comment: Mr.Hyde  you can use: WebSettings settings = _webView.getSettings(); settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true); in case of Android webview

Comment: @AlexJ I understand its a security issue, but how come firefox and safari browsers are allowing it?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. it gives me a local http://127.0.0.1:8080 address that just downloads a file when I point to it in Chrome. Using Firefox solved it for me

Answer (score 50):

**VERY SIMPLE FIX**

1. Go to your app directory
2. Start SimpleHTTPServer

In the terminal

```
$ cd yourAngularApp
~/yourAngularApp $ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Now, go to localhost:8000 in your browser and the page will show

Comment: In Python 3, it should be `python -m http.server`.

Comment: This helped out a lot! Great solution.

Answer (score 42):

The operation is not allowed in chrome. You can either use a HTTP server(Tomcat) or you  use Firefox instead.

Comment: I used firefox instead in my situation and it works. Does Chrome have more security that Firefox ? Why am I allowed to do this ....

Comment: That's the best answer for me.

Comment: Short and Simple...Worked!

Comment: really helped me too.

Comment: Hey..thanks a lot.. your answer was such a big help...saved so much of my time

Answer (score 32):

My problem was resolved just by adding `http://` to my url address.
for example I used `http://localhost:3000/movies` instead of `localhost:3000/movies`.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using this in chrome/chromium browser(ex: in Ubuntu 14.04), You can use one of the below command to tackle this issue.

```
ThinkPad-T430:~$ google-chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
ThinkPad-T430:~$ google-chrome --allow-file-access-from-files fileName.html

ThinkPad-T430:~$ chromium-browser --allow-file-access-from-files
ThinkPad-T430:~$ chromium-browser --allow-file-access-from-files fileName.html
```

This will allow you to load the file in chrome or chromium. If you have to do the same operation for windows you can add this switch in properties of the chrome shortcut or run it from `cmd` with the flag. This operation is not allowed in Chrome, Opera, Internet Explorer by default. By default it works only in firefox and safari. Hence using this command will help you.

Alternately you can also host it on any web server (Example:Tomcat-java,NodeJS-JS,Tornado-Python, etc) based on what language you are comfortable with. This will work from any browser.

Answer (score 12):

If for whatever reason you **cannot** have the files hosted from a webserver and still need some sort of way of loading partials, you can resort to using the `ngTemplate` directive.

This way, you can include your markup inside script tags in your index.html file and not have to include the markup as part of the actual directive.

Add this to your index.html

```
<script type='text/ng-template' id='tpl-productColour'>
 <div class="list-group-item">
    <h3>Hello <em class="pull-right">Brother</em></h3>
</div>
</script>
```

Then, in your directive:

```
app.directive('productColor', function() {
      return {
          restrict: 'E', //Element Directive
          //template: 'tpl-productColour'
          templateUrl: 'tpl-productColour'
      };
   }
  );
```

Comment: As I have already edited this post use
templateUrl : 'tpl-productColor'

Answer (score 6):

**RootCause:**

File protocol does not support cross origin request for Chrome

**Solution 1:**

use http protocol instead of file, meaning: set up a http server, such as apache, or nodejs+http-server

**Sotution 2:**

Add **--allow-file-access-from-files**
after Chrome`s shortcut target, and open new browse instance using this
shortcut

[image]

**Solution 3:**

use Firefox instead

Comment: Using Firefox helped me

Answer (score 5):

1. Install the http-server, running command `npm install http-server -g`
2. Open the terminal in the path where is located the index.html
3. Run command `http-server . -o`
4. Enjoy it!

Answer (score 4):

I would add that one can also use xampp, mamp type of things and put your project in the htdocs folder so it is accessible on localhost

Answer (score 2):

If you are running server already, don't forget to use **http://** in the API call. This might cause a serious trouble.

Comment: Thanks man, two hours looking for solution to same problem and was this...

Comment: Welcome bro. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

**The Reason**

You are not opening the page through a server, like Apache, so when the browser tries to obtain the resource it thinks it is from a separate domain, which is not allowed. Though some browsers do allow it.

**The Solution**

Run inetmgr and host your page locally and browse as http://localhost:portnumber/PageName.html or through a web server like Apache, nginx, node etc.

Alternatively use a different browser
No error was shown when directly opening the page using Firefox and Safari. It comes only for Chrome and IE(xx).

If you are using code editors like Brackets, Sublime or Notepad++, those apps handle this error automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is not happening in Firefox and Safari. Make sure you are using the latest version of xml2json.js. Because i faced the XML parser error in IE. In Chrome best way you should open it in server like Apache or XAMPP.

Answer (score 1):

there is a chrome extension 200ok its a web server for chrome just add that and select your folder

Comment: Excellent solution

Answer (score 0):

You have to open chrome using the following flag
Go to run menu and type
"chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir"

Make sure all the instances of chrome are closed before you use the flag to open chrome. You will get a security warning that indicates CORS is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Kirill Fuchs excellent solution and answering @StackUser's doubt - while starting the http-server, set the path till the app folder only, NOT till the html page! 
`http-server C:\location\to\app` and access `index.html` under `app` folder

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to C:/user/project/index.html, open it with Visual Studio 2017, File > View in Browser or press Ctrl+Shift+W

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. after adding below code to my app.js file it fixed.

```
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors());
```