# Mobile Web App & AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm building a mobile web "app" (in reality, a web page that changes content dynamically (no phonegap), and being built specifically for Chrome) with no internet connectivity and [I'm trying to use AJAX to load content from one html into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742070/angularjs-error-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes) and I came across that thread (I'm not using AngluarJS though).

The idea is they'll have a shortcut on their mobile android device, and it loads content from html files without ever actually going to another page.

Is this possible?

Comment: Since my experience is for AngularJS, I've added it as a comment.

The way i got around this issue with AngularJS is by having all my partials live inside script tags, using ng-template, on the main html page (usually index.html). This is the only way I found to get around the CORS issue when trying to serve html files without an actual webserver

Comment: Actually found this handy app that can run in the background and requires no live connection. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.esminis.server.php