# Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Tags: jquery, json, google-chrome

I downloaded an jQuery plugin for tree view. As I want to run the index.html in Chrome, a blank page appears, so running in web inspector, I receive the following error.

Now, I've read **why** this appears and **how to solve** (using webserver) - [thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742070/angularjs-error-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes)

**Because I will use this locally on more computers which won't have the webserver, I'm asking  if it's possible to solve this WITHOUT an webserver in chrome**.

**Usage**: Customers will click on the data they want to display in an application built in other programming language. The app will generate the code, including the JSON file. All the user (with lower IT knowledge) will have to do is click OPEN. That is going to open the index.html in his **default browser**. So it will probably work in IE, Firefox, Opera, etc. But won't work in Chrome which could gain alot of troubles.

Comment: Yes, It's solve for installing plugging.  install plugging here https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30135928/ ?

Comment: You can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local