# data loading in combo box from json file using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

keep the countries list in countries.json file. 
If load the countries into the combo box from json file, no result is coming
here is thee code details. while loading the page the countries should on the combo box.

**countries.json**

```
[
  {name: 'Afghanistan', code: 'AF'},
  {name: 'Ã…land Islands', code: 'AX'},
  {name: 'Albania', code: 'AL'},
  {name: 'Algeria', code: 'DZ'},
  {name: 'American Samoa', code: 'AS'},
  {name: 'AndorrA', code: 'AD'},
  {name: 'Angola', code: 'AO'},
  {name: 'Anguilla', code: 'AI'},
  {name: 'Antarctica', code: 'AQ'},
  {name: 'Antigua and Barbuda', code: 'AG'},
  {name: 'Argentina', code: 'AR'},
  {name: 'Armenia', code: 'AM'},
  {name: 'Aruba', code: 'AW'},
  {name: 'Australia', code: 'AU'},
  {name: 'Austria', code: 'AT'},
  {name: 'Azerbaijan', code: 'AZ'},
  {name: 'Bahamas', code: 'BS'},
  {name: 'Bahrain', code: 'BH'},
  {name: 'Bangladesh', code: 'BD'},
  {name: 'Barbados', code: 'BB'},
  {name: 'Belarus', code: 'BY'},
  {name: 'Belgium', code: 'BE'}
  ]
```

**Html File -demo.html**

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <select id="orgcountry" class="form-control input-md"></select>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var $select = $('#orgcountry');

$.getJSON('countries.json', function(data) {
$select.html('');
//iterate over the data and append a select option
$.each(data, function(key, val){
$select.append('<option id="' + val.code+ '">' + val.name + '</option>');
})

});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: firstly are you getting values from json file and secondly if you getting values then where you are appending those values to combo box ??

Comment: Hi,thank you, i have updated the code... like this way i have append the code.                                                                                         $.getJSON('countries.json', function(data) {
$select.html('');
//iterate over the data and append a select option
$.each(data, function(key, val){
$select.append('<option id="' + val.country + '">' + val.name + '</option>');
})

Answer (score 0):

You code jquery code is fine. The issue is with json file which is not proper. json object name and value needs to be double quote like below

```
[ 
  {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"},
  {"name": "Ã…land Islands", "code": "AX"},
  {"name": "Albania", "code": "AL"},
  {"name": "Algeria", "code": "DZ"},
  {"name": "American Samoa", "code": "AS"},
  {"name": "AndorrA", "code": "AD"},
  {"name": "Angola", "code": "AO"},
  {"name": "Anguilla", "code": "AI"},
  {"name": "Antarctica", "code": "AQ"},
  {"name": "Antigua and Barbuda", "code": "AG"},
  {"name": "Argentina", "code": "AR"},
  {"name": "Armenia", "code": "AM"},
  {"name": "Aruba", "code": "AW"},
  {"name": "Australia", "code": "AU"},
  {"name": "Austria", "code": "AT"},
  {"name": "Azerbaijan", "code": "AZ"},
  {"name": "Bahamas", "code": "BS"},
  {"name": "Bahrain", "code": "BH"},
  {"name": "Bangladesh", "code": "BD"},
  {"name": "Barbados", "code": "BB"},
  {"name": "Belarus", "code": "BY"},
  {"name": "Belgium", "code": "BE"}
  ]
```

Comment: i have tested with html code provided by you  along with above json content and it works perfectly for me.  if you console.log val.code and val.name inside loop, then are you getting values ??

Comment: when i load it ,  i am getting the following error in console XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/SYS002/Documents/countries.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: are you setting any path for countries.json in your actual code. If so then can you share that. And also you can refer these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742070/angularjs-error-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes

Comment: This is my code$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("entry");
   var $select = $('#orgcountry');
   console.log("entry2");
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/orgprofile/jsondata/countries.json', function(data) {
     console.log("entry");
    $select.html('');
       //iterate over the data and append a select option
       $.each(data, function(key, val){
        console.log(val.code+"_"+val.name);
       //  $select.append('<option id="' + val.code + '">' + val.name + '</option>');
    });

});
});

Comment: add ``http://`` before ``localhost`` and try.. ('http://localhost:8080/orgprofile/jsondata/countries.json')

Comment: I have added but still it is not loading  $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/orgprofile/jsondata/countries.json', function(data) {
     console.log("entry");
    $select.html('');
       //iterate over the data and append a select option
       $.each(data, function(key, val){
        console.log(val.code+"_"+val.name);
       //  $select.append('<option id="' + val.code + '">' + val.name + '</option>');
    });

Comment: if countries.json file is inside orgprofile project folder, then try with relative path instead of giving full url. I suspect issue may be because of port 8080, but not sure. Finding it difficult to help you as i unable to replicate the issue.