# trouble with jquery load method

Tags: jquery

i have a table in one html file and div in another and both files are on same server, same folder. I'm trying to use jquery load function to do the folowing. So I do :

```
$('#div').load('game.html #tbl', function(){ alert ("succes on load");});
```

As you can see I try to target #tbl which is id of table, and I get the alert that is succes, but no tables were loaded. Can tables be loaded this way?

Comment: Are you running this from a .js file or in the .html?

Comment: Yes, it can be loaded this way.

Comment: Is the id of your div, "div"? Like, `<div id="div"..`? Put some html here...

Comment: yes, div is id, am running from .html, .js is used to handle load()

Comment: note : when i try to load <ul> and couple of <li> it works

Comment: @nhrnjic6 See my answer. Make sure that all of the ids are spelled correctly, since it seems like you do have some kind of connection between the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the browser console, you probably have an error there. You've got to make sure you have the proper path, this is a relative path. If your current doesn't work, try messing around. Add `../` before the path and see if that works. I don't know your file structure so this is probably easier for you.

Another problem *could* be that you don't have the right permissions on that file, `403 Forbidden`. So, go check your web browser's console.

If you have the following file structure and run the code beneath that, everything should work fine.

```
/project_name
├── index.html
├── game.html
```

**index.html**

```
<div id="div"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>$('#div').load('game.html #tbl', function(){ alert ("succes on load");});</script>
```

**game.html**

```
<div id="tbl"><h1>I origin from another file</h1></div>
```

**EDIT:** After messing around a bit I found the solution. You **can't** run scripts with `.load` just by opening a .html file from your hard drive. You need to install WAMP/LAMP/MAMP (a local server) that you can access by entering `localhost` in the browser.

[WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

[MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/de/)

Please have a look here: [AngularJS Error: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742070/angularjs-error-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes)

Comment: It seems that all is in place but can you take a look. (sorry for pastebin) :        game.html : http://pastebin.com/qr9UtgdK                                                         home.html : http://pastebin.com/ZN9CmC0r                                                         .js : http://pastebin.com/pJbP4Fen

Comment: @nhrnjic6 Found the solution, check my answer, I updated it!

Comment: but I am running xamp, and all files are in htdocs(localhost) and like I said it gives me succes function, but it doesen't load file. Have you seen my code?

Comment: @nhrnjic6 That's strange. I copied your code and for me it works. Does `#canvas` turn blank after clicking?

Comment: @nhrnjic6 Anything in console?

Comment: it does remove content of a div so there is some action, but it doesn't load my grid

Comment: @nhrnjic6 That's because there's no content in it. Fill that table and you'll see it. This is solved!

Comment: @nhrnjic6 Are you going to mark this as the solution or did you do it in another way?