# load a file from inside of another folder in script tag

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a folder called DemoAPI.

In DemoAPI---> app.html

In DemoAPI-->  Client\public\core.js

I am trying to include `core.js` in script tag of `app.html`.

like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Client/public/core.js"></script>

core.js looks like this:


 angular.module('Todo', [])

 .controller('mainController', function($scope, $http)
 {
    $scope.formData = {};

    // get all and show them
    $http.get('/musicians')
      .success(function(data) {
            $scope.todos = data;
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });

        //get with an id
        $scope.getOneTodo = function() {
        $http.get('/musicians' + id)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.todos = data;
                      console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };
      // send the text to the node API
    $scope.createTodo = function() {
        $http.post('/musicians', $scope.formData)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.formData = {}; // clear the form 
                $scope.todos = data;
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };

    // delete 
    $scope.deleteTodo = function(id) {
        $http.delete('/musicians' + id)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.todos = data;
                      console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };

    /*
    $scope.updateTodo = function(id) {
        $http.delete('/musicians' + id)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.todos = data;
                      console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };*/

});
```

But I get an error that says :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/musicians. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

It tried to get /musician from directory where as what I mean is the url.
How do I fix this?

Comment: That's an error caused by something the script is trying to do, not something caused by failing to load the script. It's also an error you could get if you were loading the script from your local filesystem and not using node.js to serve it.

Comment: @Quentin: You are right. Please see the updated question/

Comment: The error message should be explanatory. You need a webserver.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local

Comment: Running it does no good if you don't request your HTML document from it.

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742070/angularjs-error-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes

Comment: I have ndoe js installed and started the app. How else am I supposed to use the server?

Comment: You point your browser at `http://address.of.your.node.http.server`

Comment: I did http-server c:/users/desktop/DemoAPI/server.js, but when I visit localhost at 8080, it downloads a file and shows nothing.

Comment: Well, obviously. That's what usually happens if you request a JavaScript program directly from a webserver. If you want to run client side JS then you need an HTML document to create an environment to put it in. You then put a `<script src>` tag in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `XMLHTTPRequest` assumes you're working in a web-based Protocol. However, it looks like you're environment is setup with OS based rules. Without a local server, you will struggle to work with files/JS. The proposed method, is to setup a quick local server with something like Python's `SimpleHTTPServer` module.

I usually do this by (after installing Python) navigating to the relevant folder through CLI (Command Line) and typing `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` and navigating to `http://localhost:8000`.