# AngularJS Include reusable html content

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS.

I want to include reusable html in the main html. When I try to redo [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_includes.asp), it fails. Currently I have `myUsers_List.htm`, `myUsers_Form.htm`, `myUsers.js`, and `main.html` all in one folder.

The code in `main.html` is as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="userCtrl">

<div class="container">
  <div ng-include="'myUsers_List.htm'"></div>
  <div ng-include="'myUsers_Form.htm'"></div>
</div>

<script src= "myUsers.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I can see the content in `myUsers_List.htm` and `myUsers_Form.htm` when I open `main.html` in Dreamweaver, but when I open it in browser, *it's blank.*

Could someone help me out the problem about that? Is is about the path of files or some other issue? Thanks.

Comment: Post the path of myUsers_List.htm, myUsers_Form.htm

Comment: It a new folder in Desktop, all the files are inside.

Comment: Download bootstrap.min.css, angular.min.js and put them in the same folder. In main.html include them directly <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<script src= "angular.min.js"></script>

Comment: I did that. Still same thing, show in Dreamweaver, blank in browser.

Comment: The browser is Google Chrome.

Comment: Do you have python on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

When I try to check it out in the Chrome JavaScript debugger to see whether there is any error.

Since your error is

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Desktop/New%20folder/myUsers_List.htm. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

It seems that you need to run your angular app from a web server instead of trying it locally.

Comment: Error shown as: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Desktop/New%20folder/myUsers_List.htm. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: You have to run your code from the web server instead of locally. XMLHttpRequest does not allow local file access by default. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742070/angularjs-error-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes for duplicated question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either run your project under a webserver, xampp is simple to setup.

You could perhaps download angularjs and bootstrap and serve them locally from the file system, at the minute you're using a cdn.

Also, just an observation, you're missing your  tag, on mobile so can't test if that'd cause any issues.