# AngularJS error Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource

Tags: angularjs

I'am traying to navigate between to pages with angularJS but when i open the main page with my browser it doesn't display anything 
when i look in the console i see this error :

```
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

here is my code:

ViewsTestPage:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Views Test</title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script  src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script  src="controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

the controller.js:

```
var mainApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

mainApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'UsersPage.html'

    })

   .when('/helloUser', {
    templateUrl: 'hello.html'
})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});

});
```

UsersPage :

```
Hello world <a href="#/helloUser">Hi users</a>
```

hello.html

```
 <h1> Users Page</h1>
```

any help please i'am begginner!!!!

Answer (score 1):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27743373/8638554) from a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742070/angularjs-error-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes) which has already been shared

1. Install Node.js
2. Run `npm install http-server -g` and then start `http-server C:\location\to\app`.
3. you will get the server address. For eg, `10.122.32.213:6060` (have put a random address)
4. Use the above obtained address to link your file.
5. in your case `templateUrl: 'http://10.122.32.213:6060/UsersPage.html'`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This error is happening because you are just opening html documents directly from the browser. To fix this you will need to serve your code from a webserver and access it on localhost. If you have Apache setup, use it to serve your files. Some IDE's have built in web servers, like JetBrains IDE's, Eclipse..
If you have webstorm then you can open it from webstorm.

If you have Node.Js setup then you can use http-server. Just run npm install `http-server -g` and you will be able to use it in terminal like http-server `C:\location\to\app.`

Comment: I see that response but i don't know how to do that, can you expline more, what are the steps i have to do???

Comment: You have node installed or webstorm installed?