# AngularJs route no error but not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I am creating a demo app where i am using routing. Even though there is no error in console , i am not able to see my contents. What could be wrong here. I have created two separate html file with different contents

```
<html>

        <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
            <script src = "js/junk.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body ng-app="junkapp">
            <div ng-controller = "junkController">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/first">First</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/second">Second</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div ng-view>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

```
    var app = angular.module("junkapp", ['ngRoute']);

app.controller("junkController", function($scope){

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'junk.html',
            })

            // route for the about page
            .when('/first', {
                templateUrl : 'first.html',
            })

            // route for the contact page
            .when('/second', {
                templateUrl : 'second.html',
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

config should not come under controller.

> We can’t define routes in a controller or in a service since the
>   configuration needs to happen before it gets injected into anything we
>   want to use it in. Any configuration we do to providers in the config
>   function will allow us to access pre-configured instances of these
>   providers when they are injected.

```js
var app = angular.module('junkapp',['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl : "home.html"
        }).

        when('/first', {
            template : "<p>Hi First</p>"
        }).

        when('/second', {
            template : "<p>Hi second</p>"
        });
});

app.controller("junkController", function($scope){
    $scope.text = "Welcome";     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
<p>Hi Home</p>
</script>
    <body ng-app="junkapp">
        <div ng-controller = "junkController">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/first">First</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/second">Second</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div ng-view>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `app.config` code **should not be written in a controller**. Move it outside of your controller and it will work:

```js
var app = angular.module("junkapp", ['ngRoute']);
 
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            template : "<h1>Main</h1><p>Click on the links to change this content</p>"
        })
        .when('/first', {
            template : "<h1>Banana</h1><p>Bananas contain around 75% water.</p>"
        })
        .when('/second', {
            template : "<h1>Tomato</h1><p>Tomatoes contain around 95% water.</p>"
        });
});

app.controller("junkController", function($scope) {
             
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="junkapp">
    <div ng-controller = "junkController">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/first">First</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/second">Second</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div ng-view> </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Naah.. Still i cannot see anything in the page

Comment: @AdityaKumar I've added a snippet, as you can see, it works!

Comment: Works for the template but not for templateurl

Comment: @AdityaKumar Is your app.js in the same directory as your templates (ex: junk.html)?

Comment: Yes.. The problem is with the url.

Comment: This is my home page url - file:///C:/Users/anilkumar.k/Desktop/junk/junk.html#/

Comment: The moment I clicked "first", URL changed to file:///C:/first

Comment: The path starts from **where your app.js is defined in your app directroy**, not from `C://...`

Answer (score 0):

Move the config outside of the controller.

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("junkapp", ['ngRoute']);
app.controller("junkController", function($scope){

  
});
  app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                template : "<h1>Main</h1><p>Click on the links to change this content</p>"
            })

            .when('/first', {
                template : "<h1>Banana</h1><p>Bananas contain around 75% water.</p>"
            })

            .when('/second', {
                template : "<h1>Tomato</h1><p>Tomatoes contain around 95% water.</p>"
            });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
 <body ng-app="junkapp">
        <div ng-controller = "junkController">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#first">First</a></li>
                <li><a href="#second">Second</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div ng-view>
            </div>
        </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Very strange for me... I have copy pasted your code, but still i cannot see any thing in my browser. But it is running here in code snippet

Comment: does your js file gets loaded?

Comment: yes js file is loaded. it works for template but not for templateurl

Comment: @AdityaKumar check if your templateUrls are fine

Comment: app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'junk.html',
            })

            // route for the about page
            .when('/first', {
                templateUrl : 'first.html',
            })

            // route for the contact page
            .when('/second', {
                templateUrl : 'second.html',
            });
    });

Comment: put this code .. <script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
<p>Hi Home</p>
</script>

Comment: Thanks for your help. Problem was in the URl. I found the solution here - <link>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742070/angularjs-error-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes</link>

Answer (score 0):

set config out side the controller.

```
  var app = angular.module("junkapp", ['ngRoute']);
  app.config(function($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'junk.html',
    })

    // route for the about page
    .when('/first', {
        templateUrl : 'first.html',
    })

    // route for the contact page
    .when('/second', {
        templateUrl : 'second.html',
    });
});
app.controller("junkController", function($scope){

});
```