# Angular JS Templates:- the file 'todo.tpl.html' which is a template file doesn't load? How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Creating Custom Directives</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="main">
            <my-todo list="todo" title="Angular To-do"></my-todo>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**todo.tpl.html**

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<div ng-repeat="todo in list">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.completed"> {{ todo.name }}
</div>
```

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('myTodo', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: 'todo.tpl.html',
        scope: {
            list: '=',
            title: '@'
        }
    };
});

app.controller('main', function($scope){
    $scope.todo = [
      {name: 'Create a custom directive', completed: true},
      {name: 'Learn about restrict', completed: true},
      {name: 'Master scopes', completed: false}
    ];
});
```

In the above snippet, I created a custom directive called 'my-todo', now I created a template in a different file named 'todo.tpl.html'. When I tried to load the file I get the following errors:-

1. > Failed to load file:///Users/sumo/Desktop/Tejas/GitHub/furry-happiness/customDirective/todo.tpl.html: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
2. > angular.js:14800 Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$compile/tpload?p0=todo.tpl.html&p1=-1&p2=

Can someone provide the reading links and proper documentation links to know more about templates can be helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Sajeetharan for the suggestion. But I think I have solved this problem.

As you had suggested I searched my network tag, only to find the 'todo.tpl.html' file was missing from there, though the path was correct. This was happening because of the first error which I mentioned i.e, 'the cross-domain error'.

The solution for the first error was: to store the file in any of the web-servers 'WAMP, XAMP or in my case AMPPS(for macOS)'. So I placed all the 3 file's (index.html, script.js & todo.tpl.html) inside the AMPSS folder.

Now the accessing of my code in the browser URL changed to from 'file:/// (path)' to 'http://localhost/(filename)'.

This Worked for me.

A suggestion I took from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742070/angularjs-error-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not have any errors on the network tab,  check the path of your template.

```
app.directive('myTodo', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: 'todo.tpl.html', //THIS PATH
        scope: {
            list: '=',
            title: '@'
        }
    };
})
```

it works fine **[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/0LvRtl0DZ5iBGKCUMoan?p=preview)**.

Comment: In my network Tab, I do not see the path to that file, and I tried giving the full pathname, but still, the file isn't present there.

Comment: just check the request