# Angular json query - should cors need to be used? Kindly let me know since I am new to Angular, I have very little knowledge

Tags: angularjs

I am receiving an error as below - kindly let me know what needs to be done?
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Usersest1srcdatabase.json' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to serve your app from a web server, if not already.
You can do that via:

1. [http-server](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server)
2. nginx (preferably docker)
3. [Web server for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en)

Could be a duplicate: [AngularJS Error: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742070/angularjs-error-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes)

And if you are already serving it from a web server, try reading that file using [file reader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) and not via API call.