# ajax request works with $ but not angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, http-headers

I have some jQuery that fetches data and executes a callback:

```
$(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://flash-cast-hrd.appspot.com/api/sonar/sync', 
    data: {
        source: 5,
        auth: 'JXEI....DHA2J'
    }, 
    success: displayData
});
});
```

I am trying to make the same request from my angular controller, where I have a method on the scope.

```
$scope.init = function(){

            $http.post('http://flash-cast-hrd.appspot.com/api/sonar/sync', {
                source: 5,
                auth: 'JXEI....DHA2J'
            })
                .success(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                })
                .error(function(error){
                    console.log('Error is: ' + error);
                });
        };
```

Then call it in a view:

```
<div ng-init="init()"></div>
```

When I load the page I get an error in the console:

```
OPTIONS http://flash-cast-hrd.appspot.com/api/sonar/sync 405 (Method Not Allowed) angular.js:8021
OPTIONS http://flash-cast-hrd.appspot.com/api/sonar/sync No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access. angular.js:8021
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://flash-cast-hrd.appspot.com/api/sonar/sync. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access. :8000/routes:1
Error is:
```

How can I make the angular $http.post request work?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661032/http-get-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-but-ajax-is

Comment: XMLHttpRequest error can be resolved by deploying on server, try it running after deploying to server, hope it will work

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: try to handle from server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is because of cross domain access, You can overcome by setting proxypass on your server and your request needs to include Access-Control-Allow-header also.